# DBCP database pool initialSize not picked up. Pool not expanding with load

Tags: java, sql-server, connection-pooling

I have a java application that uses DBCP database pooling to connect to SQL Server. We are using a jtds driver.

The connection configuration is below:

```
initialSize=20
maxActive=100
minIdle=20
```

So at start-up I expect to see 20 connections in the database, but I only see 16. Testing shows any value above 16 for initialSize results in 16 connections at start-up. If I set a value lower than 16 the connections hit that count correctly, which shows that the setting is being picked up.

Next I place the system under load expecting the connection count to increase. Instead of the connections increasing up to some other higher value it seems intent on remaining at 16 connections in the database. It goes up and down between 16 and ~30 but when higher values are seen it jumps up quickly to that count and then back down to 16.

I think indicates that the additional db connections are not being added back to the dbcp pool.

Checking netstat I can see that many connections end up in TIME_WAIT when this starts to happen, this indicates to me that my dbcp pool is closing the socket for the db connection, which it should not be.

I thought initial that 16 was a default starting point and that when new connections were required above that number they would be added into the pool to increase the overall size, not the case here.

We've a serious pending production issue on this so any thoughts or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

default pool size is 8, we have 2 pools which came to 16 connections in total which now makes sense.

Identified that maxIdle needed to be set for it to pick up the correct initial pool size as well. Not sure why but it works now.